# Sorting an array in O(n)

Tags: arrays, sorting, complexity-theory

Supposing you have n integers in the range from 0 to n^3-1. Is there any way you could sort them in O(n) time? I got this question for the Uni and as far as I know you can only search them in NlogN at best using mergesort or quicksort, so I suspect this being a trick question. I was also wondering why was that particular range of (0,n^3-1) given? Does it have any particular characteristic? I was also considering of using Counting Sort to do them, but as far as i know, that runs in O(n+k) time, not O(n). Please help!

Comment: You probably want radix sort. A good read: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/

Comment: if O(k) is O(N), then counting sort runs in O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Using "Counting Sort", you can sort the items in a stable way on the last n bits in O (n). Then you can sort on the middle bits, then on the highest bits. Because the keys are less than n^3 - 1, there is a fixed number of Counting Sorts (three), and three times O (n) is still O (n).

Comment: isn't that radix sort?